# repetitive data in output - xquery

Tags: xml, xquery

I'm quite new to xQuery and I've to write the following query;

> Display the title of DVDs for each director.

My xQuery is;

```
let $doc := doc("DVDStore.xml")//DVDTitle
return <Directors>{
    for $dir in $doc/Directors/Name    
        let $t := $doc[$dir = Directors/Name]/Title
        return <DVDTitles> {$dir} {$t} </DVDTitles>
    } </Directors>
```

and the DVDStore.xml is;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DVDStore>
    <DVDTitles>
        <DVDTitle>
            <Title>A. I. Artificial Intelligence</Title>
            <Date>2002-03-05</Date>
            <Studio>Universal Studios</Studio>
            <Rated>PG-13</Rated>
            <Code>1</Code>
            <Directors>
                <Name>Steven Spielberg</Name>                
            </Directors>
            <Starrings>
                <Name>Haley Joel Osment</Name>
                <Name>Jude Law</Name>
            </Starrings>
        </DVDTitle>
        <DVDTitle>
            <Title>Terminator 2-Judgment Day</Title>
            <Date>2001-01-01</Date>
            <Studio>Artisan Entertainment</Studio>
            <Rated>R</Rated>
            <Code>6</Code>
            <Directors>
                <Name>James Cameron</Name>                
            </Directors>
            <Starrings>
                <Name>Arnold Schwarzenegger</Name>
                <Name>Linda Hamilton</Name>
            </Starrings>
        </DVDTitle>
        <DVDTitle>
            <Title>Titanic</Title>
            <Date>1999-08-31</Date>
            <Studio>Paramount Home Video</Studio>
            <Rated>PG-13</Rated>
            <Code>2</Code>
            <Directors>
                <Name>James Cameron</Name>  
            </Directors>
            <Starrings>
                <Name>Leonardo DiCaprio</Name>
                <Name>Kate Winslet</Name>
            </Starrings>
        </DVDTitle>
    </DVDTitles>
</DVDStore>
```

and I'm getting the following output;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Directors>
   <DVDTitles>
      <Name>Steven Spielberg</Name>
      <Title>A. I. Artificial Intelligence</Title>
   </DVDTitles>
   <DVDTitles>
      <Name>James Cameron</Name>
      <Title>Terminator 2-Judgment Day</Title>
      <Title>Titanic</Title>
   </DVDTitles>
   <DVDTitles>
      <Name>James Cameron</Name>
      <Title>Terminator 2-Judgment Day</Title>
      <Title>Titanic</Title>
   </DVDTitles>
</Directors>
```

The problem is that when one director has directed two or more movies, like `James Cameron` has directed `Terminator 2-Judgment Day` and `Titanic` then both Titles should be grouped with the director which is happening correct but I'm getting this two times (see output).

Can somebody help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I was missing the keyword distinct-values. The working query is;

```
let $doc := doc("DVDStore.xml")//DVDTitle
return <Directors>{
    for $dir in distinct-values($doc/Directors/Name)
        let $t := $doc[$dir = Directors/Name]/Title
        return <DVDTitles> {$dir} {$t} </DVDTitles>
    } </Directors>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your processor supports XQuery 3.0 you might want to take a look at the `group by` statement as it is very elegant in my opinion and also reads much more what you actually want to do: Process each DVD title, group them by the director and output some information.

```
let $doc := doc("DVDStore.xml")//DVDTitle
return <Directors>{
  for $title in $doc
  let $director := $title/Directors/Name
  group by $director
  return <DVDTitles><Name>{$director}</Name>{$title/Title}</DVDTitles>
} </Directors>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I tried group by statement before posting the question but got the error that group by is not supported by xquery 1.0.